# SF novel identification: Cube controls Universal Collective Unconscious

Tags: story-identification, novel, technology

I first read this well written story--I believe it was a separately published short novel, not a short story--probably 15-20 or more years ago.

This SF novel had the adult heroine (a scientist or researcher of some sort?) build a box made of mysterious cubes or marked, domino like objects--each mysterious object--she slowly discovered--representing and controlling some sort of major element of a sort of Universal Collective Unconscious--composed of the unconscious minds of every single sentient in the Universe--that, when she got in "tune" with each object and manipulated it from within the box she made of them, altered the time line/reality/destiny of species.

If I remember correctly after all these years, another effect of this box she built was that time ran differently inside the box.

Comment: A lot would have to be misremembered (or maybe I'm just completely forgetting certain elements) for it to be the case, so I'm not officially marking it as a dupe, but some of it shares some similarities with Factoring Humanity by Robert J. Sawyer, subject of this other ID question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/145737/65768

Comment: @starpilotsix Yeah, that's the one I was thinking of too. The "Universal Collective Unconscious" fits, the "cubes" fit, not sure about "well written".

Comment: Do you recall if there was anything about contact with aliens from Alpha Centauri?

Comment: Thanks, but I checked out the summaries of "Factoring Humanity" and it does not appear to be the story I am searching for.

Comment: @G.Reynolds In that case, maybe you can sharpen your description by telling us in just what ways it differs from *Factoring Humanity*.

Comment: After all this elapsed time, I could be wrong, but as I recall, there was no backstory about a family situation, just the heroine alone was involved in the story.  I also believe that after a while she was spending so much time in this cube and so much time was elapsing in there vs the world outside the cube, that she was taking a bunch of food and drink inside to sustain herself.

Comment: I could be wrong, but there was no backstory about a family situation as part of the story, just the heroine alone.  I also remember she was spending so much time in this cube and so much time was elapsing in there vs the world outside the cube, that she was taking a bunch of food and drink inside to sustain herself. This cube also allowed her to focus on any particular planet, and to effect what was going on on that world/with that particular set of beings.  It comes to me that this book might have been published by either DAW or Pyramid.